# How to configure Laravel with memcache on App Engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, session, laravel, memcached

I uploaded a Laravel website to Google App Engine but cannot login because session does not work.

In `app/config/cache.php` and `app/config/session.php`, I changed:

```
'driver' => 'memcached',
```

but in `cache.php`, I see:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Memcached Servers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Now you may specify an array of your Memcached servers that should be
| used when utilizing the Memcached cache driver. All of the servers
| should contain a value for "host", "port", and "weight" options.
|
*/

'memcached' => array(

    array('host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => 11211, 'weight' => 100),

),
```

Is `'host' => '127.0.0.1'` the cause of my problem or is it something else?

[Update] When I try to use

```
'driver' => 'file',
```

and session file is store in `<bucket-name>/storage/session`. The session was created and stored, but `Response Headers` from `Server:Google Frontend` does not contain `sessionId`.

Comment: You may wish to use the official Laravel on GAE starter app, which has memcache-based session support: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/laravel

Answer (score 0):

The Memcache service on Google App Engine is not exactly the same as the standard memcached so you won't be able to run an application such as Laravel directly on App Engine without adapting it to that environment. Specifically, there isn't a hostname or IP or port for you to connect to which exposes the memcached API directly.

Fortunately, other folks have already done this so you can use the fruits of their labor, namely, take a look at [Laravel 4 on Google AppEngine for PHP](http://blog.neoxia.com/laravel-4-on-google-appengine-for-php/) and the [discussion on laravel.io](http://laravel.io/forum/09-25-2014-google-app-engine-and-vagrant) which references the above tutorial and also points to the [GAE adapter package for Laravel apps](https://packagist.org/packages/shpasser/gae-support).

Note that I haven't tried this out but looks like it should work for you; please post follow-up questions on the form where the author posted their work.